# Continued issue with ECCODES_DEFINITION_PATH for use with cfgrib

Tags: grib

I have found a few posts that address this general topic:

- [ECCODES ERROR when opening .GRIB file in Spyder/Visual Studio Code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368330/eccodes-error-when-opening-grib-file-in-spyder-visual-studio-code)
- https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/issues/85

The first link is the exact error I have had.  I follow the recourse of using this command from the windows prompt:

```
setx ECCODES_DEFINITION_PATH "C:/Users/Scott_TSYL/anaconda3/envs/for_grib/Library/share/eccodes/definitions"
```

However, the same issue occurs except the new path was inserted before the old(incorrect) path, and they are separated by a semicolon (see image).

What is going wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve error messages we ask that you show us them in full using text rather than a picture so that they can be searched and also read easily on all devices.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and **`" "` or `{}`** buttons that enables you to format any highlighted text nicely.